# Using common header to declare script src to be shared by different html files in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a folder with several HTML files. Each of the HTML file uses AngularJS and contain the same declaration like below;

```
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="js/filters.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives.js"></script>        
    <script src="vendor/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="vendor/underscore-min.js"></script>    
    <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I think this is bad practice as it violates the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle. I tried to avoid repeating the above declaration by putting them into a html partial called header.html and put this following line `<div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>` into every HTML file in the folder.

However, it did not work and the HTML page did not render the AngularJS scope correctly. Is there something wrong with my approach or are there better ways to go about doing this?

Comment: You should not use several html files but stick to on single html file for you Single Page Application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-include is an AngularJS defined directive. AngularJS needs to be loaded for it to be parsed correctly.

However, here you have included angular.min.js as part of the header.html partial. When the browser encounters the ng-include, it has no idea what it means, and simply ignores it. So none of the scripts and styles are loaded.

At a minimum, you need to have angular.min.js loaded in the main file. Everything else can then be inside the partial.

```
<script src="lib/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
...
<div ng-include src="'partials/header.html'"></div>
```

Comment: I am sorry. The Angular scope still does not render properly. The error message (Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]) leads to this webpage https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr

Answer (score 4):

AngularJS embrace the [Single Page Application](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating) concept.

Technically this means you have only 1 HTML file (lets call it index.html) which contain the `<head>` and `<body>` tags.
This means that you can put all your included script files **once** in this index.html file.

By using the [ng-route](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute) or [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) modules, you can contain other partial HTML files that will "use" the same script files.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My problem is that I would prefer to have separate tabs for different pages. Can this still be done for Single Page Application?